# How to calculate the difference between two dates in OpenERP?

Tags: odoo

In my custom module I am unable to calculate difference between two dates.

My field is

```
'date_s':fields.datetime('Start Date'),
'date_e':fields.datetime('End Date'),
```

I want to  calculate the difference  automatically  in my duration field:

```
 'Duration':fields.char('Duration'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a simple function I have written. Hope it will help you.

```
def onchange_return_date(self, cr, uid, ids, issuedate, returndate):
 a=datetime.strptime(issuedate,"%Y-%m-%d")
 b=datetime.strptime(returndate,"%Y-%m-%d")
 timedelta = b - a
 diff=timedelta.days
 return {'value': {'days':diff}}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use a function field for that purpose: https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/03_module_dev_02/#functional-fields , there are some nice examples within the addons to get a clue about this type of fields.
2. think about using date or datetime again. if you don't need time then just use date...

for further questions, just ask :-)

edit: try your function that way

```
import openerp.tools as tools
import datetime
def _get_days(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, args, context=None):
    res = {}
    for date in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        fmt = tools.DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT
        date_s = datetime.datetime.strptime(date.date_s, fmt)
        date_e = datetime.datetime.strptime(date.date_e, fmt)
        res[date.id] = (date_e-date_s).days or False
    return res
```

Comment: it's my function for calculating days ..........................  def _get_days(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, args, context=None):
        res = {}
        for date in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            res[date.id] = ((date.date_s-date.date_e).days) or False
        return res                                                    i am creating this function it gave me error like this ..res[date.id] = ((date.date_s-date.date_e).days) or False
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: i correct my function but still i got error like this                                       data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  10:52:57        and my function is            def _get_days(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, args, context=None):
        res = {}
        for date in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
            date.date_s = datetime.strptime(date.date_s, fmt)
            date.date_e = datetime.strptime(date.date_e, fmt)
            res[date.id] = ((date.date_s-date.date_e).days) or False
        return res

Comment: it give me error like this fmt = tools.DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT
NameError: global name 'tools' is not defined

Comment: did you use the import? "import openerp.tools as tools" maybe it's bit different on your system

Comment: i use it but it give me error again like this date_s = datetime.datetime.strptime(date.date_s, fmt)
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: when i was remove datetime than it will give me error like this  data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  12:44:02

Comment: add "import datetime"

Comment: ok, the problem is, you're using dateTIMEs instead of dates. do you really want to have time data? cause you named your columns "Date"

Comment: got this error date_s = datetime.datetime.strptime(date.date_s, fmt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  12:53:17

Comment: use DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT instead of ...DATE_FORMAT. i will edit my answer

Comment: now it give me error like this                                            DataError: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "-10"
LINE 1: update "advert_activity" set "duration"='-10' where id = 76

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49948/discussion-between-atul-jain-and-czoellner)