# How to calculate number of hours between two datetime fields

Tags: odoo

I have two datetime fields which are

```
 '`date_from`': fields.datetime('Submission Date').
 '`date_to`': fields.datetime('Return Date').
```

so I need number of hours between two dates in below field

```
 '`diff_hrs`': fields.float('Total Hrs').
```

how can I get it please help me

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

Add a field.function

```
"total_hours" : fields.function(_calculate_total_hours,string="Total Hours", type="float")

import datetime

def _calculate_total_hours(self,cr,uid,ids,Name=None,args=None,context=None):
    res={}
    for record in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context):
        d_frm_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(record.date_from, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
        d_to_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(record.date_to, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)

        diff = d_to_obj - d_frm_obj

        hours = (diff.seconds)/ 3600
        print hours

        diff_days = diff.days
        print diff_days

        days_hours = diff_days * 24
        print days_hours

        total_hours = days_hours + hours
        print total_hours
        res[record.id]=total_hours
    return res
```

Comment: how can I add minutes to this function please help me

Comment: I am using issued date and return date fields, first I have to draft the data without return date that means only issued date and total hours are zero. in the next stage I want to add return date and calculate total hours how can I get it please help me

Answer (score 0):

Posting If you want, May be it would help you [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473484/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-openerp/22680370#22680370).

```
def onchange_return_date(self, cr, uid, ids, date_from, date_to):
 a=datetime.strptime(date_to,"%Y-%m-%d")
 b=datetime.strptime(date_from,"%Y-%m-%d")
 timedelta = b - a
 diff=timedelta.days
 return {'value': {'days':diff}}
```